# Expand a node and two treeviews open

Tags: kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-treeview

I have **two** kendo treeview.
When I do a drag and drop an item on an other, I duplicate the item. (no node is removed on drop)

```
treeright.append(itemSource, itemDestinationKitem);
```

and it's work fine.

When I click on item (just be *drop*) the node opens, **BUT** the `itemSource` too !

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the problem.
By duplicating items `kendo ui widget` does not regenerate new `uid` , so to expand a mirror effect occurs.

To solve this problem I **SET again the datasource of treeview with call ajax** the second treeview and **new** `uid` will be affected.

**To be in the same state :**
I just add persistence on items to keep the state of the nodes `'expand'` before loading. This [kendo link](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/integration/persist-expanded-state) help me.